# Java 8 streams filtering with priority

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have code that looks like:

```
for (SomeObject object : objects) {
    if (object.getSomething() == Something.SomethingHighPriority) {
        return object;
    }
}

for (SomeObject object : objects) {
    if (object.getSomething() == Something.SomethingLowPriority) {
        return object;
    }
}
```

It is used for getting the first element in collection by some condition. Also, the priority is important. I need firstly look for the one element and just if it doesn't exist look for the second one.

I want to rewrite it using Stream API but I know that streams are used just once. 
For now I rewrote it in such way but it seems more ugly than before.

```
Optional<SomeObject> object = 
    objects.stream()
           .filter(object -> object.getSomething() == Something.SomethingHighPriority)
           .findFirst();

if (object.isPresent()) {
    return object.get();
}

object = objects.stream()
                .filter(object -> object.getSomething() == Something.SomethingLowPriority)
                .findFirst();

// No other use cases
return object.orElse(null);
```

Is it possible to make it less boilerplate?

Comment: you might want to look into Collector.(collect.toList()) so you can get all filtered objects together and not just one of them. other than that it looks just fine.

Comment: Well, streams are not always the way to go. Sometimes a simple loop as yours above is fine as well - unless you want to run the filtering in parallel. :)

Comment: sorry I don't need to get all the objects, I need to find just a one with specific priority of searching

Comment: Can you post your Something and SomeObject classes so I can compile them from my side?

Comment: "If is present then get" is not the correct way to use an Optional. You should use `orElse`, `orElseGet` etc.

Comment: @Rab sorry I can't it is a production application that is why I have hidden actual names

Comment: Iterating multiple times seems a little inefficient. If the data is not that volatile it might be better to collect the values into a map with the priority being the key.

Comment: @Thomas iterating is not inefficient per se. And when there is an element of high priority, this two-iteration approach is more efficient than any single-iteration approach.

Comment: @Holger that's true, hence I added a lot of softeners ("seems", "if ...", "might" ;) ).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can chain the two pipelines:

```
return objects.stream()
              .filter(object -> object.getSomething() == Something.SomethingHighPriority)
              .findFirst()
              .orElseGet(() -> objects.stream()
                                      .filter(object -> object.getSomething() == Something.SomethingLowPriority)
                                      .findFirst()
                                      .orElse(null));
```

An alternative would be to sort the `Stream` by `object.getSomething()` in descending order and then return the first element (if it has one of the two required values), but that would take `O(NlogN)` which is less efficient.

Comment: The check `object.getSomething() == Something.SomethingHighPriority` makes it more verbose. I would add a method inside the class and use it as a method reference in the stream.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is OK, iterating a collection twice is not a bad approach.

But if you want to do it in only one pass, you could collect to a `Map`:

```
Map<Something.Priority, Something> map = objects.stream()
    .filter(o -> o.getSomething() == Something.SomethingHighPriority
              || o.getSomething() == Something.SomethingLowPriority)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                SomeObject::getSomething,
                Function.identity(),
                (oldObject, newObject) -> oldObject));

SomeObject highPriority = map.get(Something.SomethingHighPriority);

return highPriority == null ? map.get(Something.SomethingLowPriority) : highPriority;
```

Comment: You might want to add a `filter` to skip all elements which are neither, `SomethingHighPriority` nor `SomethingLowPriority`. So the map contains at most two elements rather than an unknown number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what SomethingHighPriority means to you but you can try with Comparator. First create two predicates for high and low. Add those to the filter with the or operator beacuse you need both to compare and get the max.

```
    Predicate<SomeObject> somethingHighPriority= e -> e.getSomething() == Something.SomethingHighPriority;
    Predicate<SomeObject> somethingLowPriority= e -> e.getSomething() == Something.SomethingLowPriority;
    Optional<SomeObject> first = objects.stream()
            .filter(somethingHighPriority.or(somethingLowPriority)) 
            .max(Comparator.comparing(objects::getSomething()));

    if (first.isPresent()) {
        return first.get();
    }
    return null;
```

The max will handle the priority